# Why is it not giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question about using pointer.

```c
char *CustomString;
char str[5] = {'V', 'i', 'c', 't', '\0'};
CustomString = (char*) malloc(1);
strcpy(CustomString, str);
printf("%s\n", CustomString);
```

Why is it not giving "segmentation fault"?

The result is an output:

```
Vict
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Sometimes it appears to work correctly, right up until you put the code in production.

Comment: It's UB. The reason it works is that the allocated size is rounded up to a useful/integral multiple (usually 8 so the subsequent blocks are aligned for any purpose (e.g. `double` should be 8 byte aligned)). So, you have 7 bytes of padding that absorb the overflow. So, a bug that is latent/hidden. Try it with: `char str[] = "undefined behavior that segfaults or corrupts the heap";` And, then do `free(CustomString); CustomString = malloc(50);` and see what happens. Try running under `valgrind`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Also, rebuild your original program with: `-fsanitize=address` and see what happens when you run it ;-)

Comment: "Why is it not giving "segmentation fault"?" -- That is like asking: I drove my car through an intersection despite the traffic light showing red. Why was I able to reach the other end of the intersection safely? Why did I not collide with another car?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write past the bounds of allocated memory, you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That means the compiler makes no guarantees regarding what the program will do. It may crash, it may output strange results, or it may appear to work properly.

Just because the program could crash doesn't mean it will.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question most directly, when allocating memory most compilers' memory management schemes will adjust the allocation boundary to some fixed amount, often 16 bytes or 64 bytes. So when you allocated one byte, you actually likely got more than 1 byte. But this is behind-the-scenes behavior, and it is a VERY BAD IDEA to write any code that depends on this behavior. Change compilers (or even upgrade to a newer version of the same compiler) and all hell could break loose. It's called undefined behavior for a reason.